# testing TLV protocols

Tags: unit-testing, stun, tlv

I need to test STUN protocol. Is there any framework to test this protocol? Any other test protocol framework that tests TLV based protocol would also be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

update: Adding some more details.

STUN - [rfc5389](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5389) (along with ICE - draft-ietf-mmusic-ice-19 )is an IETF protocol for NAT traversal. STUN & ICE protocols use the TLV format for defining/encoding the body. TLV stands for Type-Length-Value and is used extensively in multiple protocols. More information about TLV is available here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value.

Comment: You are more likely to get answers if you provide some more context. Which platform do you want to use? What is the STUN protocol? What is a TLV-based protocol?

Answer (score 4):

If you want intent to **test the STUN protocol**, then [Seagull](http://gull.sourceforge.net/) is a traffic generator claiming it can be easily extended to support TLV-based protocols.

Now, if, as the tag implies, you want to **unit-test an implementation** of a STUN client, or a STUN server, then you could extend your favorite [xUnit framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUnit) with new assertions to validate TLV encoding/decoding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tlv-encoder for just TLV protocol.    [That is on gighub](https://github.com/VakhoQ/tlv-encoder).   In my opinion it's very beutifull implementaion.